# What is SilverLight

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

What is SilverLight and can be useful in C# Application?

Comment: Have you tried your favorite search engine?

Comment: +1 For right comment at the right time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverlight but quick answer is:

**Is the "Flash" equivalent technology of Microsoft.** It can be used in web sites to have richer content than HTML+ JavaScript. But recent version of HTML (HTML5) threatens Flash and SilverLight...

The main disadvantages of SilverLight and Flash technologies are that you need a "plugin" installed in all the machines that are going to visit the site. With HTML + JavaScript you only need the browser.

Comment: Can I use it in a C# windows Application and how

Comment: You can only use it in ASP.NET project as part of the page. You can't use it as part of a windows form application (or console app)... but XAML and WPF allows you to use similar funcionality in windows form application. (Both Silverlight and WPF uses xaml)

Answer (score 3):

It's basically Microsoft's version of Flash

Comment: And yes looking in Wikipedia or searching in Google would have given you all the answers you need

Answer (score 2):

A simple look at Wikipedia would give you all the answers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverlight.

In short: "Microsoft's answer to Flash", if you will.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Rich Internet Application (RIA) environment, similar to flash.

It uses [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) as a markup language and a subset of the .NET framework - so it can in the browser.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight) has more information, as do the [official site](http://silverlight.net/) and [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/).

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is a powerful development platform for creating engaging, interactive user experiences for Web, desktop, and mobile applications when online or offline.

Refer to http://www.silverlight.net/.